# Reading output buffer of Agilent 4156C using PyVisa

Tags: python, visa, gpib

I'm trying to use PyVisa to control an Agilent 4156C using its FLEX command set. The communication seems to be working OK, as I can query the instrument with *IDN? and read the status byte. I also think I'm setting up my voltage sweep properly now, as I don't see any errors on the screen of the 4156 when I execute the Python script. My problem is that when I try to read the measurement data using the RMD? command, the instrument doesn't respond, and the program errors due to timeout. Here is my current program:

```
import visa

rm = visa.ResourceManager()

inst = rm.open_resource('GPIB0::17::INSTR')
print(inst.query('*IDN?'))
inst.timeout = 6000

print(inst.write('US'))
print(inst.write('FMT 1,1'))

# Set short integration time
print(inst.write('SLI 1'))
# Enable SMU 3
print(inst.write('CN 3'))
# Set measurement mode to sweep (2) on SMU 3
print(inst.write('MM 2,3'))
# Setup voltage sweep on SMU 3
#print(inst.write('WV 3,3,0,0.01,0.1,0.01'))
print(inst.write('WV 3,3,0,-0.1,0.1,0.01,0.01,0.001,1'))
# Execute
print(inst.write('XE'))

# Query output buffer
print("********** Querying RMD **********")
print(inst.write('RMD? 0'))
print(inst.read())

print("********** Querying STB **********")
print(inst.query('*STB?'))
```

The program always hangs when I try to read after writing 'RMD? 0', or if I query that command. I feel like I am missing something simple, but just not able to find it in the available Agilent or PyVisa documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using the standard NI VISA that comes with LabView (I mention that because I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318084/agilent-visa-and-ni-visa-coexistence-and-pyvisa)).

Comment: Have you tried checking your `End of Instruction` and `End of Read` characters? Can you get it to work NI MAX's 'communicate with instrument interface'?

Comment: I have tried changing the inst.read_termination character to \r or \r\n. I'm not exactly sure how to check EOI or EOR characters... I haven't tried NI MAX's communicate with instrument interface, but I can get it to do a sweep with the example IV sweep VI that comes with the LabView driver (I believe that uses the SCSI commands though, and not the FLEX command set).

Comment: It's possible that the offending statement is actually one of the preceding ones, causing the device to freeze up and not respond to your later read() statement. Does the front panel on the device allow you to confirm that all the previous statements did what they were supposed to?

Comment: @RPM 's comment is a good one. I have encountered similar problems on a 4156C, usually due to sending a write command at the wrong time. One way to debug is to set a simple `inst.query('*IDN?')` after each write statement. Then you can be sure that the instrument is indeed locking up on the `RMD?` query and not from a previous command.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, *IDN? (and status byte and other queries) works if I put it anywhere before the RMD? command, but once I either write or query RMD?, then I can't get any more response from the instrument. For the time being I'm just using Labview...

Comment: Is there are reason you're using `inst.write('RMD? 0')` then reading instead of `isnt.query`? I seem to remember reading about `ask` being deprecated in the latest versions. Maybe you should always use `query`. (will check for docs)

Comment: I've tried using both write/read or just using query, and I run into the same kind of problem: once I write or query the RMD? command, the instrument stops responding.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and solved it.
Command XE launches the execution of current/voltages measurements with Agilent 4156C: it is thus not possible to send any additional GPIB command during execution. Even "STB?" does not work.
The only way I found to check status byte and measurement completion is checking continuously "inst.stb" paramter which is updated continuously by visa driver.
Hope this will help other users.
My code:

```
class Agilent4156C:
    def __init__(self, address):
        try:
            rm = visa.ResourceManager(r'C:\\Windows\\system32\\visa32.dll')
            self.com=rm.open_resource(address)
            self.com.read_termination = '\n'
            self.com.query_delay = 0.0
            self.com.timeout=5000
        except:
            print("** error while connecting to B1500 **")
    def execution(self):
        self.com.write("XE")
        while self.com.stb != 17:
            time.sleep(0.5)
```